# Selenium test execution via jenkins on linux machine without GUI (CLI-only) - HEADLESS MODE

Tags: linux, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, headless

This is regarding Selenium Automation Testing. I have a Jenkins job setup for some test executions.Jenkins is setup on a **Ubuntu machine without GUI (CLI Only).**
So when I run the scripts seems like it **can't find the web browser obviously**.
This job is **working perfectly fine in windows**. In Windows I get like this result.

**Window Successful Result**

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite
06/08/2015 00:04:47,996   INFO [main] (BasicTestObject.java:251) - ======BEGIN Test workflow============
06/08/2015 00:04:48,002   INFO [main] (BasicTestObject.java:252) - BEGIN Test: MlpBvt
06/08/2015 00:04:48,002   INFO [main] (BasicTestObject.java:253) - ======BEGIN Test workflow============

06/08/2015 00:04:58,862  DEBUG [main] (DefaultUIDriver.java:300) - Opened url: http://mlpdemo.qaprod.ecollege.com/
06/08/2015 00:04:58,912   INFO [main] (BasicTestObject.java:296) - -------------BEGIN Test Method-------------------
06/08/2015 00:04:58,913   INFO [main] (BasicTestObject.java:297) - BEGIN Test Method: verifyAdminLogin
06/08/2015 00:04:58,913   INFO [main] (BasicTestObject.java:298) - -------------BEGIN Test Method-------------------
06/08/2015 00:04:58,969  DEBUG [main] (DefaultUIElement.java:980) - Waiting 60000ms for element to be displayed [Locator = {By.xpath: //input[@id='clientname']}]
06/08/2015 00:04:59,058  DEBUG [main] (DefaultUIElement.java:538) - Element is displayed [Locator = {By.xpath: //input[@id='clientname']}]
06/08/2015 00:04:59,059  DEBUG [main] (DefaultUIElement.java:992) - After 89ms, element is displayed [Locator = {By.xpath: //input[@id='clientname']}]
```

**On Linux I get like this**

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite

06/08/2015 00:18:46,834   INFO [main] (BasicTestObject.java:251) - ======BEGIN Test workflow============
06/08/2015 00:18:46,839   INFO [main] (BasicTestObject.java:252) - BEGIN Test: MlpBvt
06/08/2015 00:18:46,839   INFO [main] (BasicTestObject.java:253) - ======BEGIN Test workflow============
06/08/2015 00:18:46,998  DEBUG [main] (CapturePageOnFailureListener.java:186) - CapturePageOnFailure found 2 parameters 
06/08/2015 00:18:47,002   WARN [main] (DebugUIDriver.java:311) - Called quit() on debugDriver containing null uiDriver
06/08/2015 00:18:47,025   INFO [main] (BasicTestObject.java:304) - -------------END Test Method-------------------
06/08/2015 00:18:47,026   INFO [main] (BasicTestObject.java:305) - END Test Method: verifyAdminLogin
06/08/2015 00:18:47,026   INFO [main] (BasicTestObject.java:306) - -------------END Test Method-------------------
06/08/2015 00:18:47,031   INFO [main] (BasicTestObject.java:304) - -------------END Test Method-------------------
06/08/2015 00:18:47,032   INFO [main] (BasicTestObject.java:305) - END Test Method: VerifyProfessorLogin
06/08/2015 00:18:47,032   INFO [main] (BasicTestObject.java:306) - -------------END Test Method-------------------
06/08/2015 00:18:47,036   INFO [main] (BasicTestObject.java:304) - -------------END Test Method-------------------
06/08/2015 00:18:47,036   INFO [main] (BasicTestObject.java:305) - END Test Method: VerifyStudentLogin
06/08/2015 00:18:47,037   INFO [main] (BasicTestObject.java:306) - -------------END Test Method-------------------
06/08/2015 00:18:47,038   INFO [main] (BasicTestObject.java:283) - ======END Test workflow============
06/08/2015 00:18:47,038   INFO [main] (BasicTestObject.java:284) - END Test: MlpBvt
06/08/2015 00:18:47,040   INFO [main] (BasicTestObject.java:285) - ======END Test workflow============
06/08/2015 00:18:47,100  DEBUG [main] (ProcessTool.java:36) - Getting current tool for LINUX
06/08/2015 00:18:47,100   WARN [main] (ProcessTool.java:40) - Could not find ProcessTool for LINUX
06/08/2015 00:18:47,101   WARN [main] (ProcessTool.java:88) - There was no ProcessTool for LINUX
06/08/2015 00:18:47,101  DEBUG [main] (ProcessTool.java:115) - process count for There was no ProcessTool for LINUX:1
Tests run: 12, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 11, Time elapsed: 1.976 sec <<< FAILURE!

Results :

Failed tests:
```

It is mentioned as

```
06/08/2015 00:18:47,002   WARN [main] (DebugUIDriver.java:311) - Called quit() on debugDriver containing null uiDriver
```

Please provide me some technical specialities regarding this matter. Can I run this job in linux ? Please help me out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well for unix systems you have to use [Xvfb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb) to run tests in headless mode, for jenkins you can use [xvfb plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Xvfb+Plugin)

*Simple example how to open firefox in headless mode*

```
from xvfbwrapper import Xvfb
from selenium import webdriver

xf = Xvfb()  #  xf = Xvfb(1920, 1080) - will create virtual display with 1920x1080 size
xf.start()
# browser won't appear
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://google.com")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response .But still um getting the same error.. Have you run scripts on headless mode.

Comment: No you don't, first you can use plugin it will do all stuff for you